# Global array stays empty

Tags: javascript, cordova

I want to add values in the testarray in the success function. I need to return the array  in the test function because I call this function in my script. 
The problem is that the array stays empty when I call the test function. How can I resolve this?

```
    function test()
    {
        var testarray=new Array();

        function success() 
        {

            testarray.push("test1");
        }

        return testarray;   
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like you're ever *calling* the `success` function, so what do you expect?

Comment: Has your question been answered? If not; why not?

Answer (score 1):

There is no call to `success` in your code. That is the reason `testarray` stays empty.

If you are calling `success` asynchronously then the value of `testarray` will get updated only when `success` completes execution which is at a later point in time.

To check, you can do this

```
function test()
{
    var testarray=new Array();
    function success() 
    {
        testarray.push("test1");
        console.log(testarray); //prints ["test1"]
    }
    return testarray;   //testarray is empty here because success has not yet finished.
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but did'nt wrote the full code. I call the success withvar directoryReader = fileSystem2.createReader(); 
directoryReader.readEntries(success, fail);

Comment: @michael643 If you are calling `success` asynchronously, the array will get populated only when execution of `success` is completed and not when execution of `test` is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're only declaring the success() function, never executing it. While the function doesn't make much sense to me, you could try replacing your function with:

```
(function(){
    testarray.push("test1");
})();
```

Which will define a new anonymous function and immediately call it.

Comment: I'm sorry but did'nt wrote the full code. I call the success withvar directoryReader = fileSystem2.createReader(); directoryReader.readEntries(success, fail);

Comment: @michael643 - Then you really need to provide a better example, because I have no idea what you're actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **call** the success function.

```
function test() {
    var testarray = new Array();

    function success() {
        testarray.push("test1");
    }

    success();
    success();
    success();
    return testarray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like [Narendra said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8009835/990877), at the moment you `return testarray` it has not been modified yet, because the function `success()` hasn't been called yet. Since you haven't given us more context, I'm going to assume you're doing something simple so I can provide you with a simple answer. Let's assume you want to do something like this:

```
for (testElement in test()) {
    console.log( testElement );
}
```

Now, you expect `test()` to return some results, but it returns an empty `Array`, so nothing happens.

To remedy this, you can pass what you want to do along to the test function as a function, like this:

```
function test(callback) {
    var testarray=new Array();
    function success() {
        testarray.push("test1");
        // Call the callback function:
        callback(testarray);
    }
}

myCallback = function(resultArray) {
    for (testElement in resultArray) {
        console.log( testElement );
    }
}

test(myCallback);
// After some time...
// console: test1
```

Okay, so now it works. We've defined a callback function which will be called, with the `testarray` as an argument, once the asynchronous code has finished. But it probably still doesn't do what you want, because it will only work once:

```
test(myCallback);
test(myCallback);
// After some time...
// console: test1
// console: test1
```

The moment you call `test()` again, it will create a new empty array and, when `sucess()` is called, push `"test1"` onto it. That's probably not what you want (otherwise, why would you use an `array`?)

So, how do we fix this? Well, we just take the array out of the function, like this:

```
function test(testarray, callback) {
    function success() {
        testarray.push("test" + (testarray.length+1));
        callback(testarray);
    }
}

myCallback = function(resultArray) {
    for (testElement in resultArray) {
        console.log( testElement );
    }
}

myTestArray = new Array();

test(myTestArray, myCallback);
test(myTestArray, myCallback);
test(myTestArray, myCallback);
// After some time...
// Console: test1
// Console: test1
//          test2
// Console: test1
//          test2
//          test3
```

This works for the same reason why testarray was available to the function `success()` in the first place: because JavaScript creates a "closure" over the variable. This means that because the variable is referenced inside an inner function, it will still be available inside that inner function long after the outer function has returned.

I hope this helps. :)